# C++, Using iostream library to output an uninitialized variable \ Visual Basic

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, initialization

How can I make Visual Studio (2019) print an uninitialized variable?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x;
  std::cout << x;
  return 0;
}
```

I understand this is relatively useless and uninitialized variables should not normally be used, but I would imagine there should be a way to make it print the value in the random mem location.

Error Code: C4700 - uninitialized local variable 'x' used

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, "value in random mem location" is not part of the language definition, it's a common (and bad) pedagogical technique used in "explaining" programs that don't comply with the rules of the language

Comment: Technically, there is no guarantee that this is possible. Practically, it's fairly easy to fool the compiler. Declare `void foo(int &);`, call it from `main()`, passing a reference to `x`, and in another `.cpp` file implement `foo()`.

Comment: I think you're asking how to instruct the compiler not to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method to do it.

```
int main()
{

    int num[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << num[i];
    }
}
```

In my opinion, outputting uninitialized variables does not make much sense. Maybe you want to get the address.

```
int x;
std::cout << &x;
```